# cant start session of Appium server version 1.15.1

Tags: session, server, appium, new-operator

This error message is displaying:

```
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'F:\\gautam\\android\\platform-tools\\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 192.168.0.115\:5555 shell settings delete global hidden_api_policy_pre_p_apps' exited with code 255'; Stderr: 'Security exception: Permission denial: writing to settings requires:android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS

 java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: writing to settings requires:android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
 at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.enforceWritePermission(SettingsProvider.java:1815)
 at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.mutateGlobalSetting(SettingsProvider.java:1023)
 at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.deleteGlobalSetting(SettingsProvider.java:1006)
 at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.delete(SettingsProvider.java:592)
 at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.delete(ContentProvider.java:343)
 at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsService$MyShellCommand.deleteForUser(SettingsService.java:406)
 at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsService$MyShellCommand.onCommand(SettingsService.java:289)
 at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:103)
 at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsService.onShellCommand(SettingsService.java:51)
 at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:634)
 at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:532)
 at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:735)'; Code: '255'`enter code here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An error tells you: **Stderr: 'Security exception: Permission denial: writing to settings requires:android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS**

Try following steps:

In your phone developer options (Security settings), enable USB Debugging or (or and) Disable permission monitoring. All of these settings are in your dev options.